# Jquery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

iam using jquery datepicker.

i want to reduce the length of the year dropdownlist in the jquery datepicker.

iam using dropdownlist for month and year by setting the following properties

```
$(document).ready(
 function () {

     $("#<%= txt_date.ClientID %>").datepicker({ buttonImage: "../_Images/calendar1.gif", buttonImageOnly: true, showOn: 'button', changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, yearRange: "1900:2020", duration:'fast'});

 }

);
```

do you have any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have works, [you can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ECCHr/), I assume you're talking about the actual dropdown length in the page, the vertical height of the `<select>`.  Unfortunately you can't control this, it's something the browser handles completely.